# How do I say 5 seconds from now in Java?

Tags: java, date

I am looking at the Date [documentation](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and trying to figure out how I can express NOW + 5 seconds. Here's some pseudocode:

```
import java.util.Date
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         Date now = new Date();
         now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: For new readers to this question don’t use `Date`. It was a poorly designed class in Java 1.0 and was supplanted by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) a decade ago.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

[Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is almost entirely deprecated and is still there for backward compatibility reasons. If you need to set particular dates or do date arithmetic, use a [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale.
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Does almost entirely deprecated mean its going to break if my clients upgrade their JVM?  Holy crap... this could be really bad.  Why would they kill Date?!

Comment: Very, very rarely is deprecated stuff really removed from the JRE and usually it's only done if the functionality is actively harmful. I think there is no danger that Date will be removed in any of the next few major releases. It's deprecated, because it has some severe drawbacks, but it will stay around.

Comment: @Karl I have nothing to add to Joachim's answer.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because the getTime() setTime() methods are considered 'deprecated' by the Java API. This is succinct.

Comment: @Karl, as an FYI calendar.getTime() in this example returns a Date. I don't think they're deprecating Date as much as they're deprecating some of its functionality.

Comment: Calendar has also been replaced by JodaTime.  But if you are using any external API that needs a date, it will use Date(), so that is what you should probably use, with lots of conversions.  The deprecated Date methods were not that bad either, and should have been fixed rather than adding a vast amount of complexity to deal with arcane issues like Hebrew calendars.

Comment: @Tuntable The [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project was succeeded by the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), as were the terrible `Date`/`Calendar` classes. Ex: `java.time.Instant.now().plusSeconds( 5 )`

Answer (score 62):

You can use:

```
now.setTime(now.getTime() + 5000);
```

`Date.getTime()` and `setTime()` always refer to milliseconds since January 1st 1970 12am UTC.

## Joda-Time

However, I would strongly advise you to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if you're doing anything more than the very simplest of date/time handling. It's a *much* more capable and friendly library than the built-in support in Java.

```
DateTime later = DateTime.now().plusSeconds( 5 );
```

## java.time

Joda-Time later inspired the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8.

Comment: As I press F5, your post populates with more and more useful information, it's magic =/

Comment: What about using the Calendar?

Comment: Well I couldn't let a java.util.Date question go without mentioning Joda :)

Comment: @Nick: Calendar is a very tricky API to work with properly, and doesn't let you express the idea of "just a date" (no time) or "a local date/time" etc. Go for Joda :)

Comment: Well, to add 5 seconds to "now", expressing a date with time seems useful :)

Answer (score 28):

From the one-liner-hacky dep.:

`new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000L)`

As I understand it from your example, 'now' is really 'now', and "System.currentTimeMillis()' happens to represent that same 'now' concept :-)

But, yup, for everything more complicated than that the Joda time API rocks.

Answer (score 22):

## tl;dr

```
Instant             // Use modern `java.time.Instant` class to represent a moment in UTC.
.now()              // Capture the current moment in UTC.
.plusSeconds( 5 )   // Add five seconds into the future. Returns another `Instant` object per the Immutable Objects pattern.
```

## *java.time*

Use the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible `Date` & `Calendar` classes.

### UTC

To work in UTC, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant later = Instant.now().plusSeconds( 5 ) ;
```

### Time zone

To work in a specific time zone, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime later = ZonedDateTime.now( z ).pluSeconds( 5 ) ;
```

### `Duration`

You can soft-code the amount and granularity of time to add. Use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ) ;
Instant later = Instant.now().plus( d ) ;  // Soft-code the amount of time to add or subtract.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out, in [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) it's much easier:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime added = dt.plusSeconds(5);
```

I would strongly recommend you migrate to Joda. Almost any Java date-related question on SO resolves to a Joda recommendation :-) The Joda API is supposed to be the basis of the new standard Java date API (JSR310), so you'll be migrating towards a new standard.

Comment: "java.util.Date" is to "use Joda Time" as "Random is giving me repeated values" is to "don't keep creating new instances of Random" :)

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring `Dates` and focusing on the question.

My preference is to use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` since it adds clarity to my code.

In Java,

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

5 seconds from `now` using `TimeUtil` is:

```
long nowPlus5Seconds = now + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** See [my new Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56548247/642706) using *java.time* classes. I am leaving this Answer intact as history.

---

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655450/642706) by Pascal Thivent and [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655366/642706) by Jon Skeet are both correct and good. Here's a bit of extra info.

## Five Seconds = `PT5S` (ISO 8601)

Another way to express the idea of "five seconds later" is in a string using the standard formats defined by [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The [duration/period format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601%23Durations) has this pattern `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the date portion from time portion.

So five seconds is `PT5S`.

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.8 library can both generate and parse such duration/period strings. See the [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), and [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) classes. You can add and subtract Period objects to/from [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects.

Search StackOverflow for many examples and discussions. Here's one quick example.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
DateTime then = now.plusSeconds( 5 );
Interval interval = new Interval( now, then );
Period period = interval.toPeriod( );

DateTime thenAgain = now.plus( period );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zone: " + zone );
System.out.println( "From now: " + now + " to then: " + then );
System.out.println( "interval: " + interval );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
System.out.println( "thenAgain: " + thenAgain );
```

When run.

```
zone: America/Montreal
From now: 2015-06-15T19:38:21.242-04:00 to then: 2015-06-15T19:38:26.242-04:00
interval: 2015-06-15T19:38:21.242-04:00/2015-06-15T19:38:26.242-04:00
period: PT5S
thenAgain: 2015-06-15T19:38:26.242-04:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found this from [java docs](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/AddsecondstocurrentdateusingCalendaraddmethod.htm)

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time : " + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
        + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 100);
    System.out.println("New time after adding 100 seconds : " + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
        + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
  }
}
```

Is there a convention I should be aware of?

Comment: Wow.  Java can be really verbose when it is correctly written.  Your variable name was only three letters long!

Answer (score 1):

```
        String serverTimeSync = serverTimeFile.toString();
        SimpleDateFormat serverTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(serverTime.parse(serverTimeSync));
        c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 15000);
        serverTimeSync = serverTime.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, and discuss the value it adds beyond that of the several existing answers? Stack Overflow is intended to more than a code snippet library.

Comment: am having a timeprofile.txt in device.iwas read thrw andriod bufferreader.and then adding a 15 seconds forgetting server time

Answer (score 0):

```
public class datetime {

    public String CurrentDate() {        
        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
        return currentTime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class SayHello extends TimerTask {
            datetime thisObj = new datetime();
            public void run() {
                String todaysdate = thisObj.CurrentDate();
                System.out.println(todaysdate);
            }
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 5000); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(now);
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    now = c.getTime();

    System.out.println(now);

    // Output
    Tue Jun 11 16:46:43 BDT 2019
    Tue Jun 11 16:46:48 BDT 2019
```

Comment: No, don't try this. `Calendar` and `Date` are almost entirely deprecated. Nowadays, the answer to this question is as trivial as `LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(5);`. (Where "trivial" comes with the usual disclaimers: "... unless you pass some strange time zone change with these 5 seconds, yadda yadda...")

Comment: @Marco13 No, never use `LocalDateTime` to track a specific moment, as explained in its Javadoc.  For a moment use `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `Instant`. Ex: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).plusSeconds( 5 )`

Comment: The classes used in this Answer are terrible. So terrible that Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on them years ago with the adoption of JSR 310 defining the modern *java.time* classes.  Suggesting these legacy classes in 2019 is poor advice.