# Error when trying to parse ending date

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, simpledateformat

Okay I'm struggling to understand what I'd do in this situation. I have a current date specified which gets the date a specific action is performed, and then I need to specifify a finish date, so the method will know when to finish processing.

```
public void process() {
    currentDate = getCurrentDate();

    String dateStart = lotteryStart;
    String dateStop = getCurrentDate().toString();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

try {
    d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
    d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
    //DateTime dt2 = dt1.plusMinutes(10);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);
    sendMessage(Integer.toString(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60));
    if (dt2 == dt1.plusMinutes(1)) {
    //sendMessage(Integer.toString(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60));
    //if (Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 == 500) {
        durationReached = true;
    }

    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

How would I make the end date, a specific amount of time in front of the starting date? For example, if the start date is 06/10/2013 23:02, the end date would be 06/10/2013 23:05

It's completely ignoring

```
if (dt2 == dt1.plusMinutes(1)) {
```

Except the time is increasing fine fine.

I don't know how I'd go about setting this ending date. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655357/how-do-i-say-5-seconds-from-now-in-java

Comment: Thanks, I've come across a new issue and re-worked the code a little.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `DateTime` is immutable, so when you use `dt1.plusMinutes(1)`then instance `dt1` is not changed.
New instance of `DateTime` is created. So, you should assign new instance to `dt1`.

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1).plusMinutes(1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);
```

**2)** Don't compare dates with `==`, you should use `Object::equals(Object)` instead:

```
if (dt2.equals(dt1)) {
```

**EDIT**
There is simpler way to parse `DateTime` without `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, with
[DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)  and [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
DateTime dt1 = dtf.parse(dateAsString);
```