# Finding the date corresponding to the next DayOfWeek at a LocalTime

Tags: java

Given `LocalDateTime myDate`, `DayOfWeek day` and `LocalTime time`, what is the easiest way to obtain the next date to `myDate` (let's call it `LocalDateTime next`) such that the day of the week of `next` is `day` and the time of `next` is `time`?

E.g.:

- if `myDate` is 2019-04-14 16:00:00 (Sunday), `day` is Monday and `time` is 01:00:00, then `next` would be 2019-04-15 01:00:00.
- if `myDate` is 2019-04-14 16:00:00 (Sunday), `day` is Sunday and `time` is 16:10:00, then `next` would be 2019-04-14 16:10:00.
- if `myDate` is 2019-04-14 16:00:00 (Sunday), `day` is Sunday and `time` is 15:59:00, then `next` would be 2019-04-21 15:59:00.

Comment: Please do not over-use code formatting, that makes the question very hard to read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I say 5 seconds from now in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655357/how-do-i-say-5-seconds-from-now-in-java)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question referenced above.  That is about offsetting a date by a set amount, which is not what's being asked for here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a TemporalAdjuster. Here is a simple example:

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("\nNext Friday: "+dt.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)));
```

You will, of course, need to add in the logic to change the time of the day that you get using this.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by calculating the value of how many days to add. This can be done by using the `getValue()` method of `DayOfWeek` which returns the day-of-week int value.
The values are numbered following the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday). For your given example above it would look  like something like:

```
day.getValue() - myDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
```

If it is negative just add 7 to it. If it is null, i.e same day of week compare if your time variable is before the time part of your myDate variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTimeFormatter ldt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter lt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    LocalDateTime myDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-04-14 16:00:00", ldt);
    DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("01:00:00", lt);

    LocalDateTime next = getNext(myDate,day,time);
    System.out.println(next.format(ldt));
}
public static LocalDateTime getNext(LocalDateTime ldt, DayOfWeek dow, LocalTime lt){  
    int daysToAdd = dow.getValue() - ldt.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    daysToAdd = daysToAdd < 0 ? daysToAdd +7 : daysToAdd;
    if(daysToAdd == 0 ){
        daysToAdd = LocalTime.of(ldt.getHour(), ldt.getMinute(), ldt.getSecond()).isAfter(lt) ? 7:0;
    }
    return LocalDateTime.of(ldt.getYear(), ldt.getMonthValue(), ldt.getDayOfMonth(), 
                            lt.getHour(), lt.getMinute(), lt.getSecond())
                           .plusDays(daysToAdd);
}
```