# What is the solution to increment The Date?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime

**I have this java class to insert the same line in the database every 10 seconds.
how can i do to increment the date in every insert?**

```
 @Component
 public class ScheduledTasks {

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new 
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");


private final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);


@Autowired
StandardPlanServiceImpl standardplanDao;
@Autowired
ModalityServiceImpl modalityDao;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void reportCurrentTime() throws Exception {
    log.error("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new 
Date()));        



BigInteger bigIntegerNbpers=new BigInteger("15");
String dDate = "2019091804000000";
String dpDateTime = "2019091807000000";
String fDate = "2019091811000000";
String fpDateTime = "2019091807300000";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    // milliseconds (with 2 digits)
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 2)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
 standardplanDao.save(new 
StandardPlan("red",LocalDateTime.parse(dDate, 
fmt),LocalDateTime.parse(dpDateTime, 
fmt),LocalDateTime.parse(fDate, 
fmt),LocalDateTime.parse(fpDateTime, fmt),bigIntegerNbpers,"groupe 
Test","Bloc 2"));
    log.error("The Saved Line : Début datetime: " + 
LocalDateTime.parse(dDate, fmt)+ " Fin date time :" + 
LocalDateTime.parse(fDate, fmt) + " Début pause date time : " + 
LocalDateTime.parse(dpDateTime, fmt) + " Fin pause date time : " + 
LocalDateTime.parse(fpDateTime, fmt));

 List<StandardPlan> list = standardplanDao.getAllStandardPlan();

 log.error("##########################
  ########Test##################################");
 }

 }
```

**Here is the result of my log.**

> : The time is now 2019-08-05 17:54:36+0200
>   : The Saved Line : Début datetime: 2019-09-18T04:00 Fin date time 
>   :2019-09-18T11:00 Début pause date time : 2019-09-18T07:00 Fin pause > date time : 2019-09-18T07:30
>
> ############################Test
>
> : The time is now 2019-08-05 17:54:46+0200
>   : The Saved Line : Début datetime: 2019-09-18T04:00 Fin date time 
>   :2019-09-18T11:00 Début pause date time : 2019-09-18T07:00 Fin pause > date time : 2019-09-18T07:30
>
> ############################Test

Comment: Since you can use `DateTimeFormatter` and the other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I recommend you stay away from `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is  notoriously troublesome and long outdated.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [How do I say 5 seconds from now in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655357/how-do-i-say-5-seconds-from-now-in-java)? If so, you want [this answer using java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56548247/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time is hardcoded in following lines

```
String dDate = "2019091804000000";
String dpDateTime = "2019091807000000";
String fDate = "2019091811000000";
String fpDateTime = "2019091807300000";
```

you are parsing them to LocalDateTimes

```
LocalDateTime.parse(dpDateTime, fmt)
```

After parsing you could use the plusXXX-Function (e.g. plusDays(long days)) to increment.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

Side note: if dDate etc. are constants you should extract them so they are not parsed everytime reportCurrentTime is called

For better readability you could give them better names like dDate => debutDate

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used that to increment one week :
 LocalDateTime.parse(dDate, fmt).plusWeeks(1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, create an instance variable counter and add `10*counter` seconds in the dates. At end of the function increment the counter.

```
private int counter = 0;
...
LocalDateTime.parse(fpDateTime, fmt).plusSeconds(10*counter);
...
counter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using zoned time in your output, I recommend using the ZonedDateTime class along with DateTimeFormatter.  Here's an example:

```
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(dt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")));
System.out.println(dt.plus(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")));
```